# Is there a way to check if any of list elements are in a string and replace them?

Tags: python, string, list, replace

Here is the code I've tried but it returns an output for both cases

```
alist = ['bla', 'blblblbl', 'asasa', 'blblblblblb']
astring = 'bla lalala lvlvl lblblbl asasa'
for i in alist:
    if i in astring:
        newstring = astring.replace(i, 'True')
        print(newstring)
```

Output:

```
True lalala lvlvl lblblbl asasa
bla lalala lvlvl lblblbl True
```

while I need:

```
True lalala lvlvl lblblbl True
```

Comment: Did you mean: astring = astring.replace(i, 'True') ?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest just splitting `astring`, using list comprehension to do the substitution, and joining it back:

```
print(' '.join(['True' if i in alist else i for i in astring.split()]))
```

produces:

```
True lalala lvlvl lblblbl True
```

To break this down a little:

```
print(' '.join([
    'True' if i in alist else i 
    for i in astring.split()
]))
```

- `astring.split()` == `['bla', 'lalala', 'lvlvl', 'lblblbl', 'asasa']`
- `'True' if i in alist else i` replaces `i` with `'True'` if `i` is in `alist`
- `['True' if i in alist else i for i in astring.split()]` == `['True', 'lalala', 'lvlvl', 'lblblbl', 'True']`
- `' '.join(['True', 'lalala', 'lvlvl', 'lblblbl', 'True']` turns the list into a single string with `' '` joining the list elements.

Answer (score 1):

[str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)  returns new copy of string by replacing the old  with new and you are not saving it, So just save the new copy always and perform the next `replace` actions

> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new

```
alist = ['bla', 'blblblbl', 'asasa', 'blblblblblb']
astring = 'bla lalala lvlvl lblblbl asasa'
    for i in alist:
       if i in astring:
           astring = astring.replace(i,'True')  # True lalala lvlvl lblblbl True
    print(astring)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can easily solve this with re.sub

```
alist = ['bla', 'blblblbl', 'asasa', 'blblblblblb']
astring = 'bla lalala lvlvl lblblbl asasa'
print(re.sub("|".join(sorted(alist,key=len,reverse=True)),"True",astring))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate using range function and use that index to replace the word in the split list

```
def replace(string_data,map_list):

    splited_string = string_data.split()
    for word in range(len(splited_string)):
        if splited_string[word] in map_list:
            splited_string[word] = 'True'
    return " ".join(splited_string)
```

Output:

```
'True lalala lvlvl lblblbl True'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with try and except.

```
alist = ['bla', 'blblblbl', 'asasa', 'blblblblblb']
astring = 'bla lalala lvlvl lblblbl asasa'
for i in alist:
    try:
        astring = astring.replace(i, 'True')
    except:
        pass
print(astring)
```